# Error during the Initializing a vector from an arraty of ints

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Am presently reading the book C Primer 5th Addition by Stanley B. Lippman, Josée Lajoie, Barbara E. Moo. While reading the book, I came across a line stating,

> *we can use an array to
> initialize a vector. To do so, we specify the address of the first element and one
> past the last element that we wish to copy*

The code part used to explain the above statement was,

`int int_arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; vector<int> ivec(begin(int_arr), end(int_arr));`

Upon using the following code in my compiler it throws error on the begin and end part.
The error is as follow,

```
rough1.cpp: In function 'int main()':
rough1.cpp:12:22: error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope
 vector<int> ivec(begin(int_arr), end(int_arr));
                  ^~~~~
```

My question is,

> **According to the book, the following code must not throw an error, but upon using it does throws an error. Is there something wrong with my compiler? Or, is it an older technique that is no longer used? What should I exactly do to initialize a vector from an array of ints?**

Comment: Try to `#include <iterator>`. Keep in mind that the word "throwing" is used for runtime exceptions, while you have just compiler errors.

Comment: Replace `begin` by `std::begin`. Similarly replace `end` by `std::end`

Comment: Thanks @AnoopRana it helped. May further ask why std:: helped along here although I included #include<vector> and using std::vector; in the header file. Is it always necessary to declare begin and end as std::?

Comment: Hey @DmitryKuzminov , It didn't helped but using std::begin and std::end did. And I would keep in mind about the runtime exceptions and compile error. Thanks.

Comment: @Reborn `begin` and `end` are defined in namespace `std`. So you have to be in the scope of that namespace. Which is what we do when we write `std::` . For more refer [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/namespaces-cpp?view=msvc-170). You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`begin` and `end` are defined in namespace `std`. So you have to be in the scope of that namespace. Which is what we do when we write `std::` .

So to **solve** your problem,

Replace `begin` by `std::begin`. Similarly replace `end` by `std::end`

Comment: Might be right. Might not be right. Hard to say with the paltry amount of information in the question.

Comment: @user4581301 My main objective in answering was to solve and explain the error that OP was getting. Also, OP already said that it helped with the problem at hand.

Comment: If you have to guess, make a comment.

Comment: @user4581301 Why do you think i made a guess? I don't give answers based on guesses. I saw what the error says and explained what exactly was wrong.  Also, i did  make a comment.

Comment: Could be the dreaded `using namespace std; in the code somewhere and the problem is actually a missing `#include <iterator>` There isn't enough information to pinpoint the cause.

Comment: @user4581301 **First**, the problem cannot be missing `#include <iterator>`. I already thought about that before posting my answer. This is because, the user has already included `vector` header, so **there is no need to include iterator header** since `begin` and `end` are also defined in `vector` header.  **Second**, since the OP is getting this error in the first place, it is obvious that OP has not used `using namespace std;`. So what remains is the missing `std::`.  It is simple logic.

Comment: You got me on that one.